# How to display saved localStorage data when a button is click?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Good evening, i'm an amateur programmer trying to make simple jqm web apps. i have made a full CRUD and got it to save the form to local storage. Now the problem i'm having is displaying it. i would like it to display to my Home page; under an , when the save button is clicked. But How would i go about doing that? i'm stuck.

```
<!--Home page-->
 <section data-role="page" id="home">
    <header data-role="header">
        <h1>Counter</h1>
    </header>

    <section>   
    </section>

    <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <nav data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#home"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#display"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#app"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </footer>
</section>
```

heres the js.

```
  //Store data function
     var storeData = function(key){
 var id = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000001);

    var item= {};
        item.Name=      ["Name:", $("#name").val()];
        item.category=      ["Type:", $("#category").val()];
        item.fav=   ["Favorite:", $("#fav").val()];
        item.comments=      ["Comments:", $("#comments").val()];
        localStorage.setItem(id, JSON.stringify(item));
        alert("Saved!");
        $.mobile.changePage("#add");
```

};

Comment: Some code would be nice to see

Comment: (O.T) this is the www, for some is evening, for some is morning, some does not even know that time is it :) Please post some code an don't say HI at all. We all know each other already ;)

Comment: Where is this save button?

Answer (score 0):

You can access your storage data with `window.localStorage['key']`. For example, if you saved name, birthday and gender to your locale storage you can retrieve them with:

```
var name = window.localStorage['name'];
var birthday = window.localStorage['birthday'];
var gender = window.localStorage['gender'];
```

Then you can use Javascript to load them into your elements:

```
document.getElementById('name-div').innerText = name
...
```

Of course that is assuming you have the proper HTML divs in place:

```
<div id="name-div"></div>
```

and so on. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: no i need to be able to use jquery to attach it to a click event. thank you for help.

Comment: You can do that by `$('#myBtn').click(function(e){ // code goes here });`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first up, 'id' is a randomly generated number - how are you going to be able to reference it later?

To fix this, change **var id = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000001);** to **var id = "my-form-data";**

Now you'll be able to retrieve it in later code with **var data = localStorage.getItem("my-form-data");**

Also change `<section></section>` to

```
<content>
    <div id="form-data"></div>
</content>
```

Secondly, you say you want to see this data on your home page. So change **$.mobile.changePage("#add");** to **$.mobile.changePage("#home");**

Thirdly, you want the home page to retrieve your saved form data from local storage every time the page is shown. To do this you need to hook into either the pagebeforeshow or pageshow event, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#home").on("pageshow", function() {
        var data = localStorage.getItem("my-form-data");
        #("#form-data").text(data);
    });
});
```

This will get you moving in a forward direction (I've tried to keep it simple so you can follow). You'll notice that I've not 'de-stringyfied' the data, I'll leave tht up to you.

Side note: don't use document.ready() to display data. Yes, it'll work as long as *#home* is the 1st (or only) page in your html file. But this is a bad habit to fall into. Instead, bind the *#home pageshow* event early, before the *mobileinit()* event (ready the jqm docs; events section).

Hope this helps somewhat.

Cheers,
Mark